# How can I create a for loop for this code?

Tags: r

The code below accomplishes my goal of calculating the percentage of a home-range overlapping my treatment area. However, I have 190 home-ranges. Any advice on creating a for loop or other methods to automate this process for all home-ranges? Thank you

I do not know how to create a reproducible example in this situation, but I will if anyone can guide me through the process.

````
library(sf)
library(plyr)
library(amt)
library(raster)
library(mapview)

######################################################
#read in treatment area shapefile
treatment <- st_read('C:\\Users\\kujld016\\Desktop\\All\\Projects\\Brush_Management\\imagery\\Treatment_perimeter.shp')

#check projection
projection(treatment)

#transform treatment shapefile to correct projection
treatment<-st_transform(treatment,'+proj=utm +zone=14 +ellps=GRS80 +towgs84=0,0,0,0,0,0,0 +units=m +no_defs')
projection(treatment)

#######################################################
#read in home-range shapefile
home-range <- st_read("C:\\Users\\kujld016\\Desktop\\All\\Projects\\Brush_Management\\KingR_BBM\\contour_95_151_880_25_2 2009-08.shp")

#check projection
projection(home-range)

#transform home-range shapefile projection to match treatment area shapefile
home-range <- st_transform(home-range,'+proj=utm +zone=14 +ellps=GRS80 +towgs84=0,0,0,0,0,0,0 +units=m +no_defs')
projection(home-range)

###################################################
#calculate area overlap between home-range shapefile and treatment area shapefile
pi <- st_intersection(treatment,home-range)
st_area(pi)

#calculate percentage of home-range shapefile overlapping treatment area shapefile and add value to new column
home-range$percent_area <- st_area(pi) / st_area(home-range)```
````

Comment: `KingR_BBM\contour_95_151_880_25_2 2009-08.shp` represents the one home range. Where are the other 189 stored? In that same `KingR_BBM` directory, or are they all in different directories in the `Brush_Management` directory?

Comment: @StewartMacdonald they are all stored in "C:\\Users\\kujld016\\Desktop\\All\\Projects\\Brush_Management\\KingR_BBM"

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can modify your script to loop through multiple home ranges like so:

First define your `treatment` as you have done, assuming that it is the same treatment for each home range:

```
treatment <- st_read('C:\\Users\\kujld016\\Desktop\\All\\Projects\\Brush_Management\\imagery\\Treatment_perimeter.shp')
treatment <- st_transform(treatment,'+proj=utm +zone=14 +ellps=GRS80 +towgs84=0,0,0,0,0,0,0 +units=m +no_defs')
```

Next, create a list of the 190 shapefile names using `list.files()`. For this, put all 190 shapefiles into the same folder, ideally somewhere within your parent directory. The `path` argument in `list.files()` will point to where. `"*.shp"` will include any file with the .shp extension.

```
home.names <- list.files(path = "foldername", pattern = "*.shp")
```

Now write the loop, which will iterate through each shapefile.

```
all.home.ranges <- list()

for (shp in 1:length(home.names)) {
    home.range <- st_read(home.names[shp])
    home.range.t <- st_transform(home.range,'+proj=utm +zone=14 +ellps=GRS80 
     +towgs84=0,0,0,0,0,0,0 +units=m +no_defs')
    pi <- st_intersection(treatment, home.range.t)
    home.range.t$percent_area <- st_area(pi) / st_area(home.range.t)
    all.home.ranges[[shp]] <- home.range.t
}
```

`all.home.ranges` will be a list with 190 elements, each of which is a different home range.

Note that this loop will likely take awhile to run. I would recommend testing it by changing `for (shp in 1:length(home.names))` to `for (shp in 1:length(home.names[1:2]))`, which will only do two iterations.

Comment: Thanks for the detailed response! I created the list of all home ranges, but got the following code when I ran the for loop: Error in if (nchar(dsn) < 1) { : missing value where TRUE/FALSE needed

Comment: @JLD475 Sorry, I incorrectly wrote 'for shp in home.names' rather than 'for shp in 1:length(home.names)'. The latter is correct because you're saying 'for each element in this list of 190 elements, run this code beginning with the first element'. (I mixed up my R and Python syntax)

Comment: That worked exactly as I hoped! Thank you. One last question, is it possible  to create an Id column for each home-range and populate that column with a substring of the file name?

Comment: I was able to add to the loop to create and populate an Id column for each file based on a substring of the files path by adding the following code to @Macgregor Aubertin-Young's code.                     
  ```home.range$Id <- print(file.path(home.names[i]))
  home.range$Id <- substr(home.range$Id[i],78,97)``` Thanks again for the help.